# Getting full country name with 2 letters

Tags: php, ip

I am making a website and successfully echoed the first 2 letters of the country from where user is connected. For example 'Fr' 'Us', etc. And I want php to write not 'Fr' but full name of the country. In this case 'France'. Can anyone help ?

Comment: How did you get the country code?

Comment: http://www.hauntednipple.co.uk/?p=21

Comment: Now there's a "don't click me" URL if I ever saw one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://www.iso.org/iso/list-en1-semic-3.txt 
This is a delimited text file that contains the country code and corresponding country names. Keep this file in your sever, then use a string tokenizer to convert it into a map, and use it to get the full names.

Comment: I'll tick your answer in 8 minutes.